# Using mysql_real_escape_string return empty

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-real-escape-string

I use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape `$this->piVars`.

....de/index.php?searchGenre=5

```
$searchGenre = mysql_real_escape_string($this->piVars[searchGenre]);
$result = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery('*', 'item', 'genre = ' . $searchGenre, 'title', '');
```

`print_r($this->piVars[searchGenre]);` =  string "5".

`var_dump($this->piVars[searchGenre]);` =  string(1) "9"

`print_r($searchGenre)` = empty String.

`var_dump($searchGenre)` = bool(false).

Why?

Comment: Hard to say with so little code; what is the string you're escaping? Are you connected to a database? What do you get if you `var_dump($searchGenre)` instead of `print_r`?

Comment: You may not have a valid connection to the database...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably happening because you have no open mysql connection. you must first have an open connection for `mysql_real_escape_string()` to work.

```
mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password') // open connection..
$searchGenre = mysql_real_escape_string($this->piVars[searchGenre]); // use it
```

**Note:** `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Use prepared statements with PDO (or mysqli) instead.